# Unregister delegated events in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Let's say I have this:

```
<ul>
  <li id="l1">aap</li>
  <li id="l2">noot</li>
  <li id="l3">wim</li>
</ul>
```

With this jQuery code:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {      
  console.log("You clicked on " + $(this).text());
})
```

What I would like to achieve is the following: When a user clicks one of the li's, then the event listener for *only that li* should be turned off.

This works, but removes the listeners for all the li's:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
  console.log("You clicked on " + $(this).text());

  $('ul').off('click');
})
```

I read the documentation on both jQuery's 'on()' and 'off()', but couldn't pull it together.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just add a property to each clicked li, so that it wont get processed twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

Add a class to clicked items and exclude those in your handler.

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li:not(.ignore)', function() {

  console.log("You clicked on " + $(this).text());

  // This adds a class to prevent the handler from hitting again
  $(this).addClass('ignore');      

});
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/79yp6hpq/3/

## Explanation

If you think about it, the behavior you saw makes sense. You're telling it to remove the click handler for `'ul'` which is handling all 'li' clicks.

Normally you would set up individual handlers and unbind them on click, but since delegated events cannot be set up as individual handlers (to my knowledge anyway) we have to use a workaround. I've done it by adding a class, but there are probably a couple other ways you could differentiate an item that's been clicked on.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work, see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/79yp6hpq/1/#&togetherjs=dcSb4PKeg7. I assume this is not working, because there is formally no event registered for the 'li', only for the encapsulating 'ul'

Comment: Yep, it turns out jQuery isn't quite smart enough to figure out what we're trying to do here. I've made a little workaround that should do the trick though. See updated answer.